# UI design guidelines for Android Tablets

Tags: android

Are there any UI design guidelines for the upcoming Android tablets? Looks like the Archos 7 will be available sometime this month. My question is not about supporting the screen size but more about providing a more appealing UI interface for a bigger screen device.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

It is not really UI Design Guidelines, but you can create your custom layout extend ViewGroup and be able to react to extra big resolution of the screen by putting extra components on screen and alter the layout significantly, well beyond what's possible using the build-in multi resolution XML layout mechanism.

Answer (score 1):

A great starting point would be the official [Android Design Guidelines](http://developer.android.com/design/index.html).

In particular, the sections on [Multi-pane Layouts](http://developer.android.com/design/patterns/multi-pane-layouts.html) and [Devices and Displays](http://developer.android.com/design/style/devices-displays.html) might be of interest to you.

Answer (score 0):

When understanding Android app development, one of the most significant topics to comprehend is how to make delightful mobile interfaces and interactions. This indicates understanding the patterns within the Android universe, common style guidelines, patterns, etc.

The official Android docs have an outstanding set of design resources. This section will emphasize a few key design guidelines and link to the appropriate guides. You can also check out these Android design tips for a quick overview.

Screen Size and Orientation
System Bar
Back Button
Action Bar
Widgets
Notifications
Settings
UI Elements
Fonts
Split View and Multi-Pane UI
Embedded Multimedia
Clipboard
Design Patterns